# Getting the source of an event in the Outlook Object Model

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing an Outlook plugin and am stuck on how to get the source object of an event in the call back method.

I isolated my problem in the example code down below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace Bug_Test
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {

        private static List<Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event> gObj_itemEvtList = new List<Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event>();

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the application and explorer objects...
            Outlook.Application application = this.Application;

            application.ItemLoad += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(onItemLoad);
        }

        private void onItemLoad(object Item)
        {
            Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event gObj_itemEvt = (Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)Item;

            gObj_itemEvt.Reply += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(on_Reply);

            gObj_itemEvtList.Add(gObj_itemEvt);
        }

        private void on_Reply(object Item, ref bool cancel)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem origin = Event.getSource() ;// mail on which the reply-event occured
            Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Outlook.MailItem) Item;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Hinweis: Outlook löst dieses Ereignis nicht mehr aus. Wenn Code vorhanden ist, der 
            //    muss ausgeführt werden, wenn Outlook heruntergefahren wird. Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785.
        }

        #region Von VSTO generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
        
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I the method called `on_Reply` I want to capture the source object (in Outlooks Object model case it will be one of the Outlook mail items) of the actual reply event. In the first line of the methode I am using the made up "Event.getSource()" method to better describe what I want to do.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you and best wishes,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a list of `ItemEvents_10_Event` interfaces, create a class wrapper that holds `MailItem` as a member and an event handler as a method. This way when an event fires, it will fire on a particular instance of the wrapper class, and you will be able to access the corresponding `MailItem` object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the source item in your code.

You need to keep the source item instance in a separate class/wrapper, so each class could get access to the instance which was fired the event. Read more about this approach in the [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) article which explains the basics and provide the source code.